# change class on div every 3 seconds

Tags: javascript, html, css

I hope you are all well. I was wondering if your collective genius could help me? I have a div which is a circle. I also have three CSS classes. I would like to change the class of the div and the text of the label every 3 seconds.
Anyone who could point out where I am going wrong would be extremely helpful.

Here's what I have, which at the moment doesn't seem to do anything:

```js
function loadTraffLight() {
  var traffLight = document.getElementById("traffLight");
  var status = document.getElementById("status");
  var timer;
  var go = function traffGo() {
    timer = setInterval(function() {
      if (traffLight.class == "red") {
        traffLight.className = "yellow";
        status.innerText = "O.K";
      } else if (traffLight.class == "yellow") {
        traffLight.className = "green";
        status.innerText = "Authorised";
      } else {
        traffLight.className = "red";
        status.innerText = "Stop Working";

      }
    }, 3000);
  };
}
```

```css
#traffLight {
  border-radius: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: #808080;
}
#status {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
.red {
  background: #ff0000;
}
.yellow {
  background: #ffd800;
}
.green {
  background: #00ff21;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Traffic light</title>
</head>

<body onload="loadTraffLight()">
  <h1>Traffic light effect demo</h1>
  <div id="traffLight">
    <label id="status"></label>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You are setting class using `className` then why are you reading the property using `class` ?

Comment: I did try setting with class but it did not seem to work

Comment: Do read the specs, it is always `className`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use `className` consistenly. Apart from that, I have changed the structure of your function a bit:

```js
function loadTraffLight() {
            var traffLight = document.getElementById("traffLight");
            var status = document.getElementById("status");
            var timer;

           
                timer = setInterval(function () {
                    if (traffLight.className == "red") {
                        traffLight.className = "yellow";
                        status.innerText = "O.K";
                    }
                    else if (traffLight.className == "yellow") {
                        traffLight.className = "green";
                        status.innerText = "Authorised";
                    }
                    else {
                        traffLight.className = "red";
                        status.innerText = "Stop Working";

                    }
                }, 1000);
        }
```

```css
#traffLight{
            border-radius:100px;
           
            width:200px;
            height:200px;
            border:1px solid #000000;
            margin:0 auto;
            color:#808080;
        }
        #status{
            text-align:center;
            vertical-align:bottom;
        }

        .red{
            background:#ff0000;
        }
        .yellow{
            background:#ffd800;
        }
        .green{
            background:#00ff21;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Traffic light</title>
    

</head>
<body onload="loadTraffLight()">
    <h1>Traffic light effect demo</h1>
    <div id="traffLight">
        <label id="status"></label>
    </div>

    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This goes Red, Green, Yellow for me, though I can't seem to figure out why.

Comment: @JamesPaterson Sorry, I had called the function to run lights again that's why it messed up the timings. I have corrected it now. Please check.

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

- You never call `traffGo()` in `loadTraffLight()`
- You should be comparing with `traffLight.className` instead of `traffLight.class`

See the amended code below:

```js
function loadTraffLight() {
            var traffLight = document.getElementById("traffLight");
            var status = document.getElementById("status");
            var timer;          
            function traffGo() {
                timer = setInterval(function () {
                    if (traffLight.className == "red") {
                        traffLight.className = "yellow";
                        status.innerText = "O.K";
                    }
                    else if (traffLight.className == "yellow") {
                        traffLight.className = "green";
                        status.innerText = "Authorised";
                    }
                    else {
                        traffLight.className = "red";
                        status.innerText = "Stop Working";
                    }
                }, 3000);
            };
            traffGo();
        }
```

```css
#traffLight{
            border-radius:100px;
           
            width:200px;
            height:200px;
            border:1px solid #000000;
            margin:0 auto;
            color:#808080;
        }
        #status{
            text-align:center;
            vertical-align:bottom;
        }

        .red{
            background:#ff0000;
        }
        .yellow{
            background:#ffd800;
        }
        .green{
            background:#00ff21;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Traffic light</title>
    

</head>
<body onload="loadTraffLight()">
    <h1>Traffic light effect demo</h1>
    <div id="traffLight">
        <label id="status"></label>
    </div>    
</body>
</html>
```